# Unable to add to IPagedList object or transfer List<T> to IPagedList<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I'm using the [Page List](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) ASP MVC plugin to add paging to my View as my view model contains a list that gets a little out of control at time. However, I'm running into a few issues.

- The view model contains a `List<T>` of another model object. If I make one query to the database, I'm able to change the data type of this list from `List<ZipCodeTerritory>` to `IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory>`, then simply follow the documentation to load the list from the query like so:

**View Model**

```
public IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
search.zipCodeTerritory = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                          where z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState) &&
                                z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                         select z).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

//This works but this only covers one of the three different searches that are 
//possibly from this Index page
```

- However, this presents a couple issues. For one, I'm unable to use the `.clear` method a C# `List` uses. Second, and more importantly, if I need to perform a different search where I hit the database a couple times and add the result of each query to the `zipCodeTerritory` list, I'm unable to call the `.addRange()` method. Does anyone know how to add items to an `IPagedList`?

**View Model**

```
public IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
foreach (var zip in zipArray)
{
    var item = from   z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                where  z.ZipCode.Equals(zip) &&
                        z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate &&
                        z.IndDistrnId.Equals(search.searchTerritory) &&
                        z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState)
                select z;
    search.zipCodeTerritory.AddRange(item); //This line throws the following exception:

    //PagedList.IPagedList<Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory>' does not contain a 
    //definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first 
    //argument of type 'PagedList.IPagedList<Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory>' could be 
    //found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
}
```

- I also tried simply leaving the code as it was prior to adding the paging, then just trying to cast the `List<T>` into an `IPagedList<T>` object, however this didn't work either. This method would solve all my above problems, so if anyone knows how to simply convert a `List` to and `IPagedList` that would be GREATLY appreciated.

**View Model**

```
    public IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory> pagedTerritoryList { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
search.pagedTerritoryList = (IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory>)search.zipCodeTerritory;

//This threw the following exception at runtime: 
//Unable to cast object of type  
//System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory]' to type 
//'PagedList.IPagedList'1[Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory]'.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When you query data, do you want to restart at page 0 again?  If so, why not use the approach outlined in your first step to get it into a `List<T>` (including appends, if you want) then do the `.ToPagedList()` call at the end?

Comment: @msmucker0527: Wondering if anyone knows how to add items to an `IPagedList` or cast a generic `List` to an `IPagedList`

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: The problem with that is in another search I do, I need to add items to the `IPagedList`, and an `IPagedList` doesn't have the `.addRange()` method or any other way, that I've found, to add items to it incrementally.

Comment: @NealR - right, don't convert it to the IPagedList until you're done.  Create a local temp variable of your List, AddRange() to it to your heart's content, then ToPagedList() when you're ready.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: That's what I tried in the last example. I tried to cast the `List` to an `IPagedList` and (hopefully) I did the cast wrong.

Comment: Yeah, don't cast.  Use ToPagedList().

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Thank you!! post as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To combine your various approaches together, you probably should do something like this (based on your first example):

```
var mySearch = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                      where z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState) &&
                            z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                     select z);

// Other searches, whatever; use mySearch.AddRange() here

search.zipCodeTerritory = mySearch.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Comment: Since you are enumerating `mySearch` you are actually stripping off the paging functionality PagedList offers.

Comment: By calling `ToList()` you make `ToPagedList()` pointless as the database has already returned all the records only to then page them in memory as mentioned above by @odys. So if the query returns 1 million records, all 1 million records are returned then paged in memory instead it should be paged by the database so if the page size is 10 say only 10 are returned not 1 million.

Comment: @Lankymart I'll fix it. ToList() was from the OP.

Comment: @Lankymart Hmm... I'll leave my edit, but looking at what OP was actually trying to do it's more complicated than that.