# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'List`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

When i run my view,i get this error and i know whats error is about and i know like this question asked before,so please dont vote me down let me explain :)
i tried create new viewModel and than wrapped my viewModel into PagedList.IPagedList,but when i did that i cant get access to my Propertys and than i debugged and find out i should Convert type of my ViewModel (RMAHistory) to an PagedList.IPagedList or some how My ViewModel Accept PagedList.IPagedList ,but to be honest idont know how :) :)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction :)
thanks in advance :)

Error : 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ModelNameSpace.Models.RMAHistory]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[ModelNameSpace.Models.RMAHistory].
Controller:

```
public ActionResult RMAList(string searchingrma, int? pageNumber) 
    {

        List<RMAHistory> query = db.RMAStatus.Join(db.RMA_History, u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, (u, y) => new { u, y }).
        Where(x => x.y.Ordrenummer.Contains(searchingrma) && x.y.Fakturnummer.Contains(searchingrma) || searchingrma == null).
        Select(t => new RMAHistory
        {

            OrdreDato = t.y.OrdreDato,
            AntalRMA = t.y.AntalRMA


        }).OrderBy(t => t.OrdreDato).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 5).ToList();


        return View(query);




    }
```

View:

```
@model IPagedList<ModelNameSpace.Models.RMAHistory>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<table>

<tbody>

foreach (var rma in Model)
{
<tr>

<td class="tdft">@rma.OrdreDato.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")</td>
<td class="tdft">@rma.AntalRMA</td>

 }

</tr>
}

</tbody>


</table>

 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("RMAList", new
                        {
                            pageNumber,

                            searching = Request.QueryString["searchingrma"]

                        }))
```

ViewModel:

```
public class RMAHistory
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrdreDato { get; set; }
    public string AntalRMA { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Change `List<RMAHistory> query` to `IPagedList<RMAHistory>` and remove the `.ToList()` from your query

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you thank and thank you , your awesome :) if you can post your anwser and i  mark as right anwser ,again thank you so much i was spend lot of time on this and it works :)

Comment: Tanmay has already added it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254055/unable-to-add-to-ipagedlist-object-or-transfer-listt-to-ipagedlistt is likely a better possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error Message is self explanatory. Your action method should return `IPagedList<ModelNameSpace.Models.RMAHistory>` and you are returning `List<RMAHistory>`.

So, your code would be:

```
 public ActionResult RMAList(string searchingrma, int? pageNumber) 
        {

            var query = db.RMAStatus.Join(db.RMA_History, u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, (u, y) => new { u, y }).
            Where(x => x.y.Ordrenummer.Contains(searchingrma) && x.y.Fakturnummer.Contains(searchingrma) || searchingrma == null).
            Select(t => new RMAHistory
            {

                OrdreDato = t.y.OrdreDato,
                AntalRMA = t.y.AntalRMA


            }).OrderBy(t => t.OrdreDato).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 5);


            return View(query);
        }
```

Comment: Yes i know ,i just didnt know how to convert type on my viewmodel to IPagedList until @StephenMuecke help me out :) anyway thanks for your answer it also correct :)